# How can I generate a LetsEncrypt Cert for multiple domain variants?

Tags: apache, ssl, bitnami, lets-encrypt

I'm following this guide to try and install a security certificate on my server: https://docs.bitnami.com/aws/how-to/generate-install-lets-encrypt-ssl/

I want to cover different domain name variants (.com, .co.uk www etc), so am wondering if in this line:

```
sudo lego --email="EMAIL-ADDRESS" --domains="DOMAIN" --path="/etc/lego" run
```

I'll be able to use a comma delimited list of domains?

And when I do , will this create a `.crt` & `.key` file in `/etc/lego/certificates` with a really long name? How will it generate the name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first domain name that you specify with --domains will be the one granted a certificate and the name used. The extra domain names specified with additional --domains will be part of the SAN (Subject Alternative Names).

SAN allows for multiple domain names to exist in one certificate.

Comment: And you just separate each domain name with commas?

Comment: No, with additional --domains command line options: --domains domain1.com --domains domain2.com

Comment: Thank you! That would have totally confused me. 

Comment: See also https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/how-to-specify-subject-name-on-san/52270

Comment: @LeeProbert actually you can separate the domain with commas. The separation with comma sometimes is more convenable. For example when you want to specify more domains in one ENV variable.